# Run a script when a sheet/tab is added to a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

As it says in the title, I want to trigger a script to run when the user adds a new sheet or tab to the spreadsheet. I also include using the "Duplicate" function. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following function, coupled with a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) "From Spreadsheet > On Change"

```
function newSheet(e) {
  if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_GRID') {
    Browser.msgBox('New sheet was added');  // or whatever you want to do
  }
}
```